# Nvidia 340 drivers GT240M KDE Plasma resume broken with openGL

Tags: opengl

I have openSuse distro with kernel 5.4 ( on standart kernel 5.3 nvidia 340 driver don`t work with GT240m card, system hangs on Xorg startup) and KDE plasma as workspace

The problem is when I resume laptop from suspend mode, plasma crashes and only artefacts on screen. Only restart Xorg helps

If I set Xrender as compositor, resume works normal. I have lock screen and login to desktop.  If there any chance to work with openGL ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution after hours of work )) Firstly, Xrender not good on this card when many windows opened and many workspaces enabled. OpenGL 3 is fastest solution. But with it, there are problems described upper

Solution is :

1. If after suspend login screen work or desktop  shown, it can looks with artefacts or font broken. So restart plasmashell is solution. You can run plasmashell --replace
2. Chrome browser and electron apps also may corrupt, it this case solution is restart chrome GPU process. Just kill it, and chrome restarts it
3. If X shows artefacts and no possible use interface, just black screen with parts of windows, solution is to restart kwin process.

Automation possible if attach scripts to unblock screen event  ( plasmashell --replace) and system-sleep systemctl entry

PS

Something like this also catched on nvidia GTX 550 with 390 drivers